# asp:chart control don't show anything when in web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP: chart control don't show anything when it publish to web servers but it is normal when it in development computer,and that the website not show any error info.Just show a bad picture following:
[web server show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGPw0.jpg)

[Development show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjduL.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to add some code to replicate the issue and add details like, which chart control are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file change ChartImageHandler as below (Change Uri from ~/tempimg to ./tempimg) or use a storage type of memory

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="Storage=file;Timeout=360;Url=./tempimg/;deleteAfterServicing=false;"/>
```

Comment: Think you answer my question,but using you method,the web site run a error of web.config error.I must ask off you ,it is need for make a dir of name temping in web site.